# Adding a send email option in a form for a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After my users fill out a form, I want them to have the option of sending or not sending an email.

I can do this easily in the controller by doing something like:

```
send_email if params[:entry]
```

but I'm not sure how to introduce this param under my form_for, since it isn't part of the model.

How can I get this param to show up in the view and be available upon submit?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `#check_box_tag` form helper in the `form_for` block

It can be something as simple as this:

```
<%= form_for @notice do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :text, 'Notice Text' %>
  <%= f.text_area :text %><br />
  <%= label_tag 'entry', 'Send Email?' %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'entry' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```